# How to join three RDDs in to a tuple?

Tags: python, apache-spark, tuples, rdd, pyspark

I am relatively new to Apache Spark in Python, and here is what I am trying to do. I have input data as following.

- `rdd_row` is a RDD of row indices (i),
- `rdd_col` is a RDD of column indices (j),
- `rdd_values` is a RDD of Values (v).

The above three RDDs are huge.

I am trying to convert them to a sparse rdd matrix

```
rdd_mat= ([rdd_row],[rdd_col],[rdd_values])
```

i.e,

```
rdd_mat=([i1,i2,i3 ..],[j1,j2,j3..], [v1,v2,v3 ..])
```

I have tried:

```
zip where rdd_row.zip(rdd_col).zip(rdd_val)
```

but it ends up giving

```
[(i1,j1,v1),(i2,j2,v2) ..]
```

and

```
rdd1.union(rdd2)
```

won't create a tuple.

Help guiding me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: What you are trying to do is not capturing the benefit of RDDs probably. Why would you want an RDD with 3 lists parallelized inside it?

Comment: Thanks Dean. My input is broken down into 3 lists - rows, colums, and values. I was under impression, an RDD with 3 lists would enable me to perform matrix operations in an easier way.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately at this point (Spark 1.4) Scala and Java are much better choice than Python if you're interested in linear algebra. Assuming you have input as below:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(323) 

rdd_row = sc.parallelize([0, 1, 1, 2, 3])
rdd_col = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 4])
rdd_vals = sc.parallelize(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=5))
```

to get a `rdd_mat` of the desired shape you can do something like this:

```
assert rdd_row.count() == rdd_col.count() == rdd_vals.count()
rdd_mat = sc.parallelize(
    (rdd_row.collect(), rdd_row.collect(), rdd_vals.collect()))
```

but it is a rather bad idea. As already mentioned by @DeanLa parallel processing here is extremely limited not to mention every part (a whole rows list for example) will end up on a single partition / node.

Without knowing how do you want to use the output it is hard to give you a meaningful advice but one approach is to use something as below:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

coords = (rdd_row.
    zip(rdd_col).
    zip(rdd_vals).
    map(lambda ((row, col), val): (row, col, val)).
    cache())

ncol = coords.map(lambda (row, col, val): col).distinct().count()

rows = (coords.
    groupBy(lambda (row, col, val): row)
    .mapValues(lambda values: Vectors.sparse(
        ncol, sorted((col, val) for (row, col, val) in values))))
```

It will create a rdd of pairs representing row index and sparse vector of values for a given row. If you add some joins or add group by column you can implement some typical linear algebra routines by yourself nevertheless for full featured distributed data structures it is better to use Scala / Java [CoordinateMatrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#coordinatematrix) or another class from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed`

Comment: Thanks zero323.
This is precisely what I did and I kept running in to issues. Using .collect() is not efficient with huge rdds. I have been using zip followed by lambda functions to get around, but I kept thinking there must be a better way.

As you suggested Java CoordinateMatrix might work in my case. Thanks again.

Comment: Collect is a definitely a problem but structure by itself is much worse. It is possible to obtain the same effect using combination of `groupBy` and `union` but in practice it wouldn't be better at all. Desired structure with small number of huge elements is simply not a good fit for Spark.